# How would I modify this code to get a exception error?

Tags: java, oop, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch

My goal is to modify my setters to throw tractorException if invalid values are passed in then modify my main method to try and catch the exceptions. The problem is I do not know how to modify my setters to make a exception error. Please Help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class tractorException
{
      protected String name;
      protected int VehicleID; 

     public String setName(String name) 
       {
           return this.name = name;

       }

       String getName() 
       {
           return this.name;        
       }

     public int setVehicleID(int VehicleID)
       {
           if (VehicleID <= 0 || VehicleID > 100000) 
           {
             return -1;
           } 
           else 
           {
              this.VehicleID = VehicleID;
              return VehicleID;

           }
        }

          public int getVehicleID()
        {
            return this.VehicleID;
        }

      tractorException()
      {
         setVehicleID(0);
         setName("");
      }

  @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Tractor Name= " + name + "VIN= " + VehicleID;

    }
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense - first off, `TractorException` should be a subclass of `Exception` or `RuntimeException`. Second, you probably don't want all that code to go in `TractorException`. Having a look at a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
public class TractorException extends Exception
{
    //implement whatever methods are necessary
}
```

In a class that represents a `Tractor`.

```
public int setVehicleID(int VehicleID) throws TractorException
{
   if (VechicleID <= 0) {
     throw new TractorException("Invalid VIN: " + VehicleID);
   }
   else {
     this.VehicleID = VehicleID;
     return this.VehicleID;
   }

}
```

In your main method, catch TractorException

Comment: Thank you I understand a little now.